# How to shrink the padding of a <DIV> element to zero before shrinking the content?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to wrap my head around creating responsive web pages and currently try to understand how the HTML layouting engine decides which areas to shrink when.

My goal is to have two nested DIVs, the outer one using a padding at both sides for readability, and the inner one showing the actual content:

```css
.section {
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="content">
    Hello, World!
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, when shrinking the browser window, I'd like to *first* collapse the padding (i.e. the red area) and only actually have the content area become smaller once the padding is gone. Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: if you need to check if the padding is zero - I would use jQuery. on window resize.

Comment: else you could write specific media queries, that first shrink the sections padding, and another query that shrink the content

Comment: the use of padding isn't the solution in this case ... what you want is to use max-width with the blue div and center it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.section {
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="content">
    Hello, World!
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know if this what you wanted. I simply gave the `content` a fixed width and centered it.

In order for this to become responsive I suggest you play around with `content`'s width property on different `@media` queries to be able to adjust on all kinds of devices.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I guess if I choose the content width as a breakpoint, I could have a media query which switches the width of the content to 100% as soon as I hit 300px.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe no need media query simply replace width with max-width

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with use of css media queries. [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aQZoVM) is the basic codepen.
I've just added following media query to the existing css. You can change the width in media query as you want. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) is the media query related stuff that can help.

```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .section {
        background-color: lightblue;
        padding-left: 5%;
        padding-right: 5%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .section {
        background-color: lightblue;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution! The only downside seems to be that you get a slight 'jump' in the layout, I guess: if I read this right (I'm still somewhat new to CSS media queries) you'll see a jump in the padding from 45 pixels to 0 pixels once you move the browser width from 900px to 899px, right?

Comment: Yes. You are right there will be sudden change in padding once the width goes above 900px and above 600px respectively.